# Accessing Hardware using Swift language

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am currently in the design phase of an App to access a Bluetooth device (BLE 4.0) and was trying to get some help from people who know objective C. Now i hear there’s a new language "Swift" by Apple which is more easy to learn and program.  Does Swift have capability to access HW sensors on phone? Is Swift just front end interface but accessing HW logic has to be done using Objective-C?

Please help me understand this so that it would help me choose which way to go. Thanks a lot.

-Prashanth

Answer (score 1):

Swift is a replacement for objective-c, you can do everything with it

Comment: I would more precisely say, you can write nearly the same apps with Swift like one can write with Objective-C.

Comment: There's a couple types that don't have a Swift equivalent, which causes the occasional framework method to be unavailable in Swift. `vector_float3` for example doesn't translate to Swift, and therefore causes a couple SpriteKit and SceneKit methods to be Objective-C only. Depending on what you're doing, you might have to write an Objective-C wrapper or two in an otherwise Swift-only app.

Comment: Thanks guys. Was checking one of Swift learning guides, it didn't talk about HW interface. Does one have any pointers? Sorry didn't do much Google yet